# Prevent Collapsible toolbar from completely collapsing

Tags: android

How can I prevent the toolbar from completely collapsing. I have an image which is displayed. I don't want the user to completely collapse the toolbar. I just want the user to scroll down a little and prevent the user from further moving the toolbar.

Comment: Add Screenshot to clear your question

Comment: A want a layout like the one in the Backdrops wallpaper app. Where i can only scroll till a limit. [Sample Image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/RjPgOwPI3NtFn4FY3F9mnKm-8O46Gcz2DDX6qHknpS3A5TF2mz6HCxjiQGSXntQhQn5U=h900-rw)